# php echo xml documents with header

Tags: php, xml

php code

```
<?php
$xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$xml.="<db_entry id=\"$model->id\" doi=\"$model->identifier\">";
$xml.="<dataset>";
$xml.="</dataset>";
$xml.="</db_entry>";
$xml=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $xml);
$output= simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $output->asXML();
```

when i run it, it can't shows the xml format in the webpage(shows all text without xml tag).
so i add the header(), but it shows XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
<?php
    $xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    $xml.="<db_entry id=\"$model->id\" doi=\"$model->identifier\">";
    $xml.="<dataset>";
    $xml.="</dataset>";
    $xml.="</db_entry>";
    $xml=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $xml);
    $output= simplexml_load_string($xml);
    echo $output->asXML();
```

the webpage shows empty, but in the page view source it shows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<db_entry id="5" doi="110039"><dataset/></db_entry>
```

and has three blank lines at the beginning.

Comment: Try echoing `$xml` and see what you get.

Comment: same result, only shows the text

Comment: Do you see the XML if you do `View Source` in the browser?

Comment: in the view source, it shows xml format in two line, but has three blank lines at the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't show format? Is there an XSLT stylesheet defined? Can you post your XML content and even a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: @Parfait i post the content

Comment: your browser interprets the tags, use `echo htmlspecialchars(...)`

Comment: What browser are you using? IE, FF, Chrome, and Opera shows XML content and markup.

Answer (score 1):

Change this area

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
<?php
    $xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

To

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
    $xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
```

**REASON**

By closing php in one line and opening again in the next line you are writing a line to the output. As you know, things outside `<?php ?>` tag will directly print to the browser. And as per XML rule, you cannot put anything before the `<?xml ...?>` part.

Comment: it still has the error  XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything else before the `<?php` tag and you do not use `?>` tag before you make the XML declaration.

Comment: @AntiGMO You mentioned that View Source shows 3 blank lines at the beginning. So you probably have some blank lines before the first `<?php`.

Comment: @TareqMahmood I checked, the first line is <?php

Answer (score -2):

if you can try to print using this so that its work properly

```
echo '';print_r($output);echo '';die;
```